# AngularJS, Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I study AngularJS directives at this link: [Directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

When i reached the last example about: **Creating Directives that Communicate**

I did find this line(from script.js):

```
title: '@' // Line 33 at the script.js
```

The problem is that i don't know what this line means, I do know that title is an isolated scope property but what is the `@`, I have learned that:

- `'=' is where the attribute name is the same as the value`
- `'=info' where info is the attribute`

But the documentation from the link above is not explaining what is the `@`, My best guess is that when the `@` is the value, The value assigned to the `title` property is the value from the title attribute, But i am not so sure if anyone can help me understand what it is i will be very thankful, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: https://egghead.io/lessons here is thing that is better documentation. See video about @ parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the site Rantiev.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@` is a type of isolated scope binding (like `=`). However, `@` says to only take the *value* of the attribute and *not* create a two-way bind to the outer scope.

So, if you wanted to use some value in the directive, but this value did not change for the duration of that instance of the directive, then `@` is a good choice.

A quick example would be if you wanted to set a color for a directive template:

```
<my-color-box color="red"></my-color-box>
```

Then, in the directive you use the attribute like this:

```
app.directive('myColorBox', function() {

   return {
      restrict: E,
      scope: {
         color: '@'
      },
      template: '<div style="background-color: {{color}}"></div>'
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Davin, I think i got it now.

Comment: Can be tricky at first to understand, but once you start using them it will make sense.